# Rails 4.2 + NGINX - application root won't load

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails-4.2

My server setup works for a Rails 4.0 app, but fails on a 4.2 app.  I get this error:

```
An error occurred.

Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently unavailable.
Please try again later.

If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should check the error log for details.
```

NGINX config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    root /home/deploy/myapp/current/public;
}
```

NGINX error.log:

```
2014/10/13 16:17:06 [error] 9261#0: *9 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: ***.***.***.***, server: localhost, request: "GET / H$
```

Rails production.log:

```
W, [2014-10-13T16:11:57.305892 #10891]  WARN -- : Warning. Error encountered while saving cache a4b17298d22d34199795f642dc5b96ec8d58cc6c/orders.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<$

W, [2014-10-13T16:11:57.314170 #10891]  WARN -- : Warning. Error encountered while saving cache a4b17298d22d34199795f642dc5b96ec8d58cc6c/pages.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous class #<C$

W, [2014-10-13T16:11:57.319744 #10891]  WARN -- : Warning. Error encountered while saving cache a4b17298d22d34199795f642dc5b96ec8d58cc6c/registrations.css.scssc: can't dump anonymous c$
```

If I manually put in an index.html file in the public directory, I can see that.  But it fails when I want to go to the root path of the app.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so this is a bit embarrassing.  To further troubleshoot my application, I started in production mode on my local machine, and when I loaded the app I got the following error on the web page:

```
Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`
```

So that was it.  I guess I missed this new security feature by jumping straight from Rails 4.0 to 4.2  Not sure why it didn't show in the logs, but at least I found it eventually.

Comment: This happens to me almost every time!  A nice error page would be better than just a silent fail...